# I can't make my OnClick method work in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I've been trying to delete data from firebase with an OnClick RecyclerView method, but nothing works. I can't even make my OnClick method works. I have watched videos and tutorials, I've tried so much stuff and nothing helps...
Here is my adapter class:

```
public class myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter.myviewholder>{

ArrayList<datamodel> dataholder;

public myadapter(ArrayList<datamodel> dataholder) {
    this.dataholder = dataholder;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    return new myviewholder(view);

}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(dataholder.get(position).getImageurl()).into(holder.CircleImg);
    holder.header.setText(dataholder.get(position).getHeader());
    holder.descr.setText(dataholder.get(position).getDescr());
    holder.price.setText(dataholder.get(position).getPrec());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataholder.size();
}

class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CircleImageView CircleImg;
    TextView header, descr, price;

    public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        CircleImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circle1);
        header = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtheader1);
        descr = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdescr1);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtprecio1);

    }
}
```

And my fragment (the one that have the recyclerView):

```
public class articulos extends Fragment {

private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private String uid;

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private Context mContext;
private myadapter myadapter;


RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<datamodel> dataholder;

public articulos() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment articulos.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static articulos newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    articulos fragment = new articulos();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_articulos, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dataholder= new ArrayList<>();
    getDataFromFirebase();

    //datamodel ob1 = new datamodel("Esta nueva", "5000MXN", "wwsad.adasd", "asdasdsa");
   // dataholder.add(ob1);

    //recyclerView.setAdapter(new myadapter(dataholder));


    return view;
}



private void getDataFromFirebase() {

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
    Query query = myRef.child("Usuarios").child(uid).child("articulos");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            ClearAll();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                datamodel datamodel = new datamodel();

                datamodel.setImageurl(snapshot1.child("imageurl").getValue(String.class));
                datamodel.setDescr(snapshot1.child("descripcion").getValue(String.class));
                datamodel.setHeader(snapshot1.child("nombre").getValue(String.class));
                datamodel.setPrec(snapshot1.child("precio").getValue(String.class));
                dataholder.add(datamodel);
            }

            myadapter = new myadapter(dataholder);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new myadapter(dataholder));
            myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}

private void ClearAll(){
    if(dataholder != null){
        dataholder.clear();

        if(myadapter != null){
            myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
    dataholder = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Button mbtnNuevoArticulo = view.findViewById(R.id.btnNuevoArticulo);

    mbtnNuevoArticulo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.agregarart);
        }
    });

}
```

If anyone can tell me what to do and how to do it, please.. **I need it so bad**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try set onclicklistener on viewholder class

```
class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    CircleImageView CircleImg;
    TextView header, descr, price;

    public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        CircleImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circle1);
        header = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtheader1);
        descr = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdescr1);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtprecio1);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


  @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
       //do something when clicked
   }
}
```

Comment: im add missing implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can apply onclick listener by using following code :

```
holder.header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something.
    }
});
```

add this code in your `onBindViewHolder` of Adapter. Just make sure to change the id of holder.

full code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(dataholder.get(position).getImageurl()).into(holder.CircleImg);
    holder.header.setText(dataholder.get(position).getHeader());
    holder.descr.setText(dataholder.get(position).getDescr());
    holder.price.setText(dataholder.get(position).getPrec());
    holder.header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should avoid object creation inside onBindViewHolder since it may be called a lot during layouts and scrolling causing new OnClickListeners to be created and immediately thrown away. It's better to have the ViewHolder implement View.OnClickListener and attach itself to the itemView. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Create object of view inside your view holder and also initialize button.setOnClickListener(this) inside viewHolder itself and setting on click inside onBinfViewHolder(...)(only in JAVA). In kotlin you just need to set on click method inside onBindViewHolder(...).

Example:

```
 class YourAdapter():RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourViewHolder>() {

 class YourViewHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
   
    val yourButton:Button = view.findViewById(R.id.landingViewBtn)
 }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
  
   
    holder.yourButton.setOnClickListener {
        //do Something
        val intent = Intent(context,nextActivity::class.java)
       
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
  }
}
```